# Timeout while deploying Azure Web Application

Tags: c#, azure, web-applications, msbuild, webjob

I’m writing a script to deploy my Azure Web Application.

Msbuild works great for when I have the source code and want to compile and upload it to the WebApp. 
On other occasions I want to upload a build drop that doesn’t contain the source code but only dlls and binaries. Then I zip the directory and upload the zip using the following command:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method PUT -InFile $zipFilePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

A lot of files are being uploaded and I therefore get a timeout:

> Invoke-RestMethod : 500 - The request timed out.           500 - The request timed out.  The web server failed to respond within the specified time.

I found that there is a [Load Balancer limit](https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/blog/new-configurable-idle-timeout-for-azure-load-balancer/) of 230 seconds but I’m not sure how to change it. I tried settings SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT to 600 in my application settings but I still get the same timeout.

My questions are:
1.  How can I change the Load Balancer timeout in the Azure WebJob and avoid that exception?
2.  Is there a better/easier way to upload the zip to the Azure WebJob?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change the Load Balancer timeout in the Azure WebJob and avoid that exception?

Per my understanding, you could only configure TCP Idle timeout for your Cloud Services and Virtual Machines. But as the documentation mentioned as follows:

> A common practice to keep the connection active for a longer period is to use [TCP Keep-alive](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-101) (You can find .NET examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.settcpkeepalive.aspx)). Packets are sent when no activity is detected on the connection. By keeping on-going network activity, the idle timeout value is never hit and the connection is maintained for a long period.

I checked [Invoke-RestMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) and found the **KeepAlive** is enable by default and the **TimeoutSec** is an indefinite time-out by default.

> Is there a better/easier way to upload the zip to the Azure WebJob?

You could use ftp tool (e.g. [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client)) and upload your binaries as follows:

[image]

Also, you could leverage [Kudu console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) or azure portal. For more details, you could refer to [WebJobs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs) about deployment.